# I am trying to keep track of the two largest numbers in an array

Tags: java

I know that my array has the correct information (i checked) but in my for loop it is coming up with the wrong values.

```
        int mostFrequent = 0;
        int secondMost = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<256;i++){
            if (counter[i] > mostFrequent) {
                secondMost = mostFrequent;
                mostFrequent = i
            } else if (counter[i] < mostFrequent && counter[i] > secondMost){
                secondMost = i;
            }
        }
```

I know that I am saving the integers mostFrequent and secondMost as the index of the array, that is on purpose. I am comparing the values of the array but I want to save the indexes of those values. The correct values should be 32 and 101 for the indexes but it is not coming out correctly.

Comment: @mrsahuashish Your proposed edit is merely a slight rewording. No improvement whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing value with index!
Use `counter[i] > counter[mostFrequent]` instead of `counter[i] > mostFrequent`

```
        int mostFrequent = 0;
        int secondMost = 0;
        for(int i =0;i<256;i++){
            if (counter[i] > counter[mostFrequent]) {
                secondMost = mostFrequent;
                mostFrequent = i
            } else if (counter[i] < counter[mostFrequent] && counter[i] > counter[secondMost]){
                secondMost = i;
            }
        }
```